# Stop beanstalk restarting my app after failure

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

On my EC2 instance created by beanstalk, by app crashes due to an error but gets restarted over and over again (not the whole EC2 instance, just the app running on it). How can I stop restarts from happening?